# How to merge/combine/insert of 2 different arrays based on key value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I need to merge 2 different kinds of array based on the same key value
1st Array:

```
Array{
 [0]=>Product{
  [name]=>car
  [type]=>honda
 }
 [1]=>Product{
  [name]=>motorbike
  [type]=>suzuki
 }
 [2]=>Product{
  [name]=>superbike
  [type]=>audi
 }
[3]=>Product{
  [name]=>car
  [type]=>suzuki
 }
}
```

2nd Array:

```
Array{
 [0]=>Seller{
  [name]=>andy
  [handle] =>car
 }
 [1]=>Seller{
  [name]=>davies
  [handle] =>superbike
 }
 [2]=>Seller{
  [name]=>kevin
  [handle] =>motorbike
 }
}
```

Final Output:

```
 Array{
     [0]=>Product{
      [name]=>car
      [type]=>honda
      [seller]=>kevin
     }
     [1]=>Product{
      [name]=>motorbike
      [type]=>suzuki
      [seller]=>kevin
     }
     [2]=>Product{
      [name]=>superbike
      [type]=>audi
      [seller]=>davies
     }
    [3]=>Product{
      [name]=>car
      [type]=>suzuki
      [seller]=>andy
     }
    }
```

So from the example array and the output that i given. I m trying to merge 2 different arrays into 1. `Array 1` is the list of numerous product while `Array 2` is the list of seller name and info. I m trying to assign each product according to the seller handle.

Therefore i m trying to merge 2 different arrays based on the key value which is `product[name]` and `seller[handle]`to produce the `final output` as shown above

Comment: You'd probably want to mention your desired behaviour on edge-cases (eg. a 2nd seller that sells cars)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pretty standard approach:

```
$result = array();

foreach ($sellers as $seller) {
    // For each seller, loop through products and 
    // check if the name matches the sellers handle
    foreach ($products as $product) {
        if ($product['name'] == $seller['handle']) {
            // When a product has a name that matches the seller's handle, 
            // add it to the result array 
            $result[] = array(
                'name' => $product['name'], 
                'type' => $product['type'], 
                'seller' => $seller['name']);
        }
    }
}
```